# A characterisation of flatness

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, finitely-generated, flatness

A left $R$-module $M$ is flat if and only if every morphism $f:K\to M$ , where $K$ finitely presented, factors through a finitely generated projective left $R$-module.

I have found a proof of this theorem in T.Y.Lam's book "Lectures on Modules and Rings", they use the Equational Criteria for flatness. But I am looking for other proofs without using linear equations. Can any one help me?

Comment: Isn’t this almost Lazard’s theorem on flat modules…?

Comment: Yes it is, I have seen the proof but I'm looking for others